# Prove that $f∈\mathbb{F}_{p}(X,Y)$ implies $f^p∈\mathbb{F}_{p}(X^p,Y^p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F=\mathbb{F}_{p}(X,Y)$ be the field of rational functions in variables $X$, $Y$ over the finite field of p elements. Let $K=\mathbb{F}_{p}(X^p,Y^p)$ be a subfield. Prove that for any $f∈F$, $f^p∈K$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f=\sum_{i,j}a_{i,j}X^iY^j\implies f^p=\sum_{i,j}a_{i.j}X^{pi}Y^{pj}$$

(Remember that $\;(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p\pmod p\;,\;\;a,b\in\Bbb F_{p^n}\ldots\;$)

Comment: Thank you, it completely answers my question.